# How to Compile a While Loop statement in PySpark on Apache Spark with Databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I'm trying send data to my Data Lake with a While Loop.

Basically, the intention is to continually loop through code and send data to my Data Lake when ever data received from my Azure Service Bus using the following code:

This code receives message from my Service Bus

```
def myfunc():
  with ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(CONNECTION_STR) as client:
      # max_wait_time specifies how long the receiver should wait with no incoming messages before stopping receipt.
      # Default is None; to receive forever.

        with client.get_queue_receiver(QUEUE_NAME, session_id=session_id, max_wait_time=5) as receiver:
          for msg in receiver:
              # print("Received: " + str(msg))
              themsg = json.loads(str(msg))
              # complete the message so that the message is removed from the queue
              receiver.complete_message(msg)
              return themsg
```

This code assigns a variable to the message:

```
result = myfunc()
```

The following code sends the message to my data lake

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([json.dumps(result)])
spark.read.json(rdd) \
  .write.mode("overwrite").json('/mnt/lake/RAW/FormulaClassification/F1Area/')
```

I would like help looping through the code to continually checking for messages and sending the results to my data lake.

I believe the solution is accomplished with a While Loop but not sure

Comment: what is the reason to use service bus instead of natively supported EventHubs?

Comment: That is a very good question. I have been trying to convince my employer to use EventHubs but to no avail. It is absolutely madness using Service Bus, but unfortunately I can't change their mind. May be I could get you to speak to my employer :-). But seriously its really annoying as I know if they would use EventHubs it would solve so many of my problems. Anyhow, do you have any thoughts on how to solve my question?

Comment: And I know streaming Service Bus isn't supported with Databricks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you're using Spark doesn't mean you cannot loop

First off all, you're only returning the first message from your receiver, so it should look like this

```
with client.get_queue_receiver(QUEUE_NAME, session_id=session_id, max_wait_time=5) as receiver:
    msg = str(next(receiver)) 
          
    # print("Received: " + msg)
    themsg = json.loads(msg)
    # complete the message so that the message is removed from the queue
              
    receiver.complete_message(msg)
    return themsg
```

To answer your question,

```
while True:
    result = json.dumps(myfunc())

    rdd = sc.parallelize([result])
    spark.read.json(rdd) \  # You should use rdd.toDF().json here instead 
      .write.mode("overwrite").json('/mnt/lake/RAW/FormulaClassification/F1Area/')
```

Keep in mind that the output file names aren't consistent and you might not want them to be overwritten

Alternatively, you should look into writing your own `Source` / `SparkDataStream` class that defines SparkSQL sources so that you don't need a loop in your main method and it's natively handled by Spark

Comment: Hi OneCricketeer, I could kiss you if this works. Going to check it out shortly

Comment: Hi OneCricketeer, I'm getting the following error:
NameError: name 'client' is not defined. And the error is pointing to ```result = json.dumps(myfunc())```

Comment: No wait, I think it might be working ...

Comment: Even I hate this solution - I should be using EventHubs. But once again, thank you

Comment: Hi OneCricketeer, I was wonder if you could help me tweak the code you provided to re-run in the event of an error? For example, once I lose a connection I get the following error:  ```SessionLockLostError: The lock on the session has expired. Callers should request the session again.```. Can you help me tweak the code to re-run after getting the error?

Comment: I think I will need to include some kind of try / except code, but not sure